# How to change multiple input[type=range] simultaneously

Tags: html, jquery

Hope everyone is doing great! I'm trying to change multiple `input[type=range]` simultaneously.

For example, if there are two `input[type=range]`

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="21" name="rangeone" id="rangeone">  
<input type="range" min="0" max="55" name="rangetwo" id="rangetwo">
```

If I use the first one, then the second should also get trigger with it, and vice versa. I hope you got my point

I think this is possible with JQuery, but I don't know how to do it.

Thank you.

Comment: _"the second should also get trigger with it"_... in what way? Should get the same value? Should increase by the same amount? Linearly? Proportionately?

Comment: If the range of the first element is set to 1, then the second one should get increased by 1.5 (For example: on 1, the second element range would be 1.5, and on 2, the second element range would be 3 and so on) @Phil

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you're saying. Please edit your question to give some concrete examples

Comment: check this website (https://thepetsupplyguy.com/ferret-cage-size-calculator/) you will get my point then

Comment: Nope, it's still completely unclear what you're asking

Comment: If you see that tool, you will notice that both ranges elements are running at the same pace and position, and on changing the first input[type=range], the second one is getting increment by 1.5

Comment: Looks more like 2.5 to me but anyway, you should be able to do that with my answer by setting appropriate `min`, `max` and importantly `step` values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the two to synchronise proportionately, something like this should work

```js
const ranges = $("input[type=range]")

ranges.on("input", function() {
  // calculate the proportional value of the changed input
  const ratio = this.value / (this.max - this.min)
  
  // apply the proportional value to every other input
  ranges.not(this).val(function() {
    return ratio * (this.max - this.min) + parseInt(this.min)
  })
})

$("button").on("click", () => {
  ranges.each((_, range) => console.log(range.name, range.value))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" min="0" max="20" name="rangeone" id="rangeone">  
<input type="range" min="0" max="30" step="0.5" name="rangetwo" id="rangetwo">

<button type="button">Get values</button>
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I was looking for but thank you! I guess I need to do some tweaking on it (I was trying to achieve something like this https://thepetsupplyguy.com/ferret-cage-size-calculator)

Comment: @shaktigoyal I've updated my answer to match your _"1.5 scale"_ description. In order to accept fractional values, you need to set a fractional `step` value

Comment: You are awesome! This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you @phil

Comment: One quick question though! When I set the value of step attribute to 1, it is supposed to go like this 1,2,3,4 but for some unknown reason, the gap between each step is 10 (10,20,30...) @phil

Comment: @shaktigoyal do you think you could put a demo together on https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: check it out https://jsfiddle.net/pa6Ls4n8/1/ the gap between each step is 10 despite setting the step attribute value to 1 @phil

Comment: Fixed it! It was a typo mistake

Comment: @shaktigoyal out of interest, what was the typo?

Comment: I mistakenly had put the 0 outside the span tag (the span tag where the result would be shown)

Answer (score -1):

You can do that with simple javascript using `event listeners` and `loops.`

```js
// a  function to change all the ranges
function change_value(from_elem) {
  document.querySelectorAll('input[type="range"]').forEach(
    e=>{
      // dont change for the input that is changed by the user
      if (e.id !== from_elem.id) {
        e.value =  from_elem.value;
      }
    }
  )
}


document.querySelectorAll('input[type="range"]').forEach(
  e=>{
    e.addEventListener('change', ()=>{change_value(e)})
    console.log('Done')
  }
)
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="21" name="rangeone" id="rangeone" value="0">  
<input type="range" min="0" max="21" name="rangetwo" id="rangetwo" value="0">
```

Comment: Why did you change the range `min` / `max` values?

Comment: To maintain the bar's balance when it is changed.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question! Appriciate it